# Load audio from local memory and play sprites

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, howler.js

I am not an expert so please be patient with me.

I would like to know how to load an audio from file and play a sprite. 
This is the pseudocode, hope that it will help to make you understand:

- Ask for the path of the audio
- Write the timeA in milliseconds (When the program has to start to play)
- Write the timeB in milliseconds (When the program has to stop to play)
- Play the Sprite from timeA to timeB

I am using this library https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js. Is there a way to create automatically the sprites with this?

Please help me! Thank you in advance.

I know that it would be better to post some code, but I really do not know where to begin.

Comment: Have you checked the answer? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand aright, you want to load a sound file and play a part of it from one given position to a second given position.

So take your timestamps and build the sprite as shown below. I added some more code for your convenience. While it would be easy to calculate the timestamps before if you know the duration aof your sound file, it may be also interesting to calculate timestamps from the end of a file with unknown duration. Therefore you'l have to load the file and thereafter you can get the duration (see the part within the "onload")

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="howler.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="buttonBefore">Loading...</button>
  <button id="buttonToPlay">Loading...</button>
  <button id="buttonAfter">Loading...</button>
  <button id="buttonLastSecond">Loading...</button>
  <script>
    var timeA = 100;
    var timeB = 200;
    var soundFile = new Howl({
      urls: ['./sound.mp3'],
      onload: function () {
        document.getElementById('buttonBefore').onclick = function () {
          soundFile.play('before')
        }
        document.getElementById('buttonBefore').firstChild.data = "Play before";

        document.getElementById('buttonToPlay').onclick = function () {
          soundFile.play('toplay')
        }
        document.getElementById('buttonToPlay').firstChild.data = "Play toplay";

        document.getElementById('buttonAfter').onclick = function () {
          soundFile.play('after')
        }
        document.getElementById('buttonAfter').firstChild.data = "Play after";

        document.getElementById('buttonLastSecond').onclick = function () {
          soundFile.play('lastSecond')
        }
        document.getElementById('buttonLastSecond').firstChild.data = "Play lastSecond";

        soundFile.sprite({
          "before": [0, timeA - 1],
          "toplay": [timeA, timeB],
          "after": [timeB + 1, soundFile._duration * 1000],
          "lastSecond": [soundFile._duration * 1000 - 1000, soundFile._duration * 1000 - 1],
        });

      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```